# Updated 3A+ and now video playback (HDMI) shows 4 screens, Red, Green, Blue, B&W

Tags: streaming-video

Updated my 3A+ and now streaming websites like youtube show 4 screens at playback. What could that be? I'm using a 2,4A power source. Before updating was working just fine.
Thanks for the help
[image: **enter image description here**]

Comment: `Updated` using `apt`?

Comment: Sorry, i don't know what apt means. i updated using the tool on the os.

Comment: `apt` or also `apt-get` are the main tools to manage the operating system for installing and updating software packages. They only run on the command line in a terminal window and are mostly used to troubleshoot installation problems.

Comment: Yes, I updated like this, and the problem still persists. Any other ideas?